# Homebrewでインストールしたpythonを標準で使いたい

Tags: python, homebrew

HomebrewでインストールしたPython2.7を使いたいのですが、現状、

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

となっており、使えません。どうしたら良いでしょうか。

```
$which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

となり、Apple提供のpythonを利用しないようにしたいと考えております。

OS:OSX 10.10.5

追記
.bash_profileに追記を考えましたが、

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

##                                                                              
# Your previous /Users/*******/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/********/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2012-10-27_at_16:53:55                  
##                                                                              

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-10-27_at_16:53:55: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.                                            
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.       


# Setting PATH for Python 3.4                                                   
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave                          
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7                                                   
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave                          
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

既に`expo‌​rt PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`の記載がございました。
いかがすればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: なにもしなければ環境変数のPATHに/usr/local/binが優先されるようにセットされているはずなのですが。.bash_profileに明示的に`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`と書いて、一旦ログアウトしてみてください

Answer (score 1, accepted):

追記された.bash_profileの内容から、現在のPATHの優先順位は次のようだと考えられます。
（上にいくほど順位が高い）

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
それ以外のPATH
```

ということで、最初の行の `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` をファイルの末尾に移動させれば /usr/local/bin の実行ファイルを最優先に検索してくれるようになるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！/usr/local/bin下のpythonが使えました。

Answer (score 1):

いくつか方法があります。いずれの設定も完了したらターミナルを立ち上げ直してください。

### aliasを設定する

~/.bashrc に以下の行を追加してコマンドの別名を登録します。シェルスクリプトなどの別プロセスからpythonを起動させる場合にはこの設定は使えません。

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python
```

また、~/.bash_profile に .bashrc を読み込む設定 (`source ~/.bashrc`) がなければ、追加で記述しておく必要があります。

### PATHを設定する (ユーザレベル)

~/.bash_profile に以下の行を追加してPATHの優先順位を変更させます。

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

### PATHを設定する (システムレベル)

/etc/paths を管理者権限で編集してPATHの優先順位を変更させます。変更はすべてのユーザに影響します。

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```